# Inherit attributes in component definition

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a basic `image` component and within it there is an `img` element. Is there a way to pass the native `img` attributes to `image` without having to define them all, such as `alt` and have them all applied to the `img` tag?

Here is some pseudo code of what I mean:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'image',
  template: '<img [src]="src" [...attrs]>'
})
export class ImageComponent {
  @Input() attrs;
}
```

```html
<image img.alt="Some Alternative Value">
  <another-component></another-component>
</image>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this can be done (if it's what you're after ..)

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'image',
  template: '<img #imgRef [src]="src">'
})
export class ImageComponent {
  @ViewChild('imgRef') imgRef: ElementRef<HtmlElement>;
  @Input() attrs;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // assuming attrs is a key/value object
    Object.entries(this.attrs).forEach(([key, value]) => {
     this.imgRef.nativeElement.setAttribute(....)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: How would this component be utilized?

Comment: You'd pass an object into the component e.g. `<image [attrs]="{alt: 'some name', etc: 'etc'}">`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware of, it is not possible to reflect attributes from the component host into the component view, without having to manually define `@Input()`s for every possible attributes.

An possible alternative, if it applies to you, is to [project](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) an `img` element from outside your `image` component, inside the component's view.

```html
<image>
  <img alt="Some Alternative Value">
  <another-component></another-component>
</image>
```

That way, you basically have the `img` element exposed, where you can freely add attributes, among others.